# Rails ActiveRecord::Base.logger show only execution time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to get Rails to only show SQL execution times and not show the SQL queries themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

```rb
class TimeLogFormatter < Logger 
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    time_capture = msg.match /\[\d+m\w.*\([\d\.]+ms\)/
    if time_capture
      "\e#{time_capture}\e[0m\n"
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = TimeLogFormatter.new(STDOUT)
```